# Rails-like routing framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

is there any rails-like routing I can use in my non-rails app? I really like the way of defining url matching. Something like:

```
if matcher.match("/myapp/cart/:id/create")
    puts matcher[:id]
end
```

Something similar. I would prefer simple solution to that. Maybe a snippet or reference to some code that can be used. Or a library. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want Rails but nice routing, I'd suggest Sinatra. That's basically a Rack-App with a router and no other overhead.

Comment: Yeah I know that. Unfortunately I just need some library (class) for that. Its quite complex in Rails. I will look on Sinatra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with rack also

https://github.com/mynyml/simple_router

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Sinatra may be perfect for you:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want sinatra like routes inside a rails app you may want to try [sinatrify](https://github.com/shime/sinatrify)

[astaire](https://github.com/carllerche/astaire) also seems to offer the same functionality but is not compatible with rails >= 3.2 with which i tried to use it.